# How to create VM instance in Google Compute Engine?

Tags: linux, ssh, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am new to Google Compute Engine. I want to create a  Web Server having following properties:

- 1 Core
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.1 64 bit
- RAM 8 GB
- HDD: 100 GB
- SSH, JDK 1.7
- Apache Web server as the proxy to Jboss App Server
- Enable HTTP / 80 and HTTPS /443  on public IP
- Access Mode – SSH/SCP

I created a new instance having Linux Red Hat 7.1 and machine type `n1-standard-2` that provide 2 CPU cores and 7.5 GB of RAM. Can I define exactly one core with 100 GB HD and 8 GB RAM? And how can I define access mode SSH/SCP ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*** I'd like add this update to my answer: Now it's possible to customize the machine type based on your hardware requirements.***

When creating a Compute Engine VM instance you will need to specify a [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types). There is no way to specify amount of CPU and memory. However, you can select a machine type which will be close to your hardware requirements.

For the persistent disk, using the `gcloud` command tool you can create a disk with the desired size:

```
$ gcloud compute disks create DISK_NAME --image IMAGE --size 100GB --zone ZONE
```

Then create your VM instance using your root persistent disk:

```
$ gcloud compute instances create INSTANCE_NAME --disk name=DISK_NAME boot=yes --zone ZONE
```

Since [Automatic Resizing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#repartitionrootpd) of root persistent disks is not supported by Compute Engine for Red Hat Enterprise operating system, you will need to manually repartition your disk. You can visit [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#manualrepartition) for information about repartitioning a root persistent disk.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I define exactly one core with 100 GB HD and 8 GB RAM?

No, you can only use predefined machine shapes with the preassigned amounts of CPU and RAM.

See [Kamran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30740735/3618671) for how to create a disk of a different size, that is separate from CPU and RAM.

> And how can I define access mode SSH/SCP?

That's automatically done for you and it's already running an SSH server. Note that by default, it uses SSH keys, not passwords. To connect to your GCE VM, see [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/#sshing); the command would look like:

```
gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE-NAME --project=PROJECT --zone=ZONE
```

You can also connect to your instance [via your web browser](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/#sshinbrowser) by using the <kbd>SSH</kbd> button in the [Developers Console](https://cloud.google.com/console).

To use `scp`, use the flags that are provided for the [`ssh` command](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/#standardssh), e.g.,

```
scp -i KEY_FILE \
    -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
    -o CheckHostIP=no \
    -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    [source-files ...] \
    USER@IP_ADDRESS:[dest-location]
```

or vice versa to copy them back.